# Dynamically populating Selectboxes from Database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

hope you can help as I'm starting to pull my hair out :) There seems to be loads of links around regarding this but I can't get any of them to work, so I'm just going to ask in straight laymans terms.

I have a database... it has fields for Region, Area, Manager, Employee

I have a front end form, with select boxes in it...

When you choose the Region, I need the Area selectbox to dynamically populate with the relevant areas from the database without refreshing the page

Then when the Area selct option is chosen the Manager one needs to populate. and so on.

No doubt this needs an ajax/ Jquery solution, of which as I've said there's many articles around about this but I just cannot get them to work.  I've NEVER even attempt AJAX before today so sincere apologies if this is a total noob thing to be asking.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Thankyou!

Okay I have this for my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $('#Region').change(function() {
  // remove all options in Area select
 $('#Area').html('');
  // find the new Region selected
  var selected_region = $('#Region').val();
  // get new options from server and put them in your Area select
  $('#Area').get('Ajax/getArea.php?Region=' + selected_region);

});
});
```

and this for my PHP:

```
<?php

// get province id passed in via `post` or `get`
$region = $_REQUEST['Region'];

// get the districts in that province
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT AREA FROM Sales_Execs WHERE Region ='$region'";

// link to your database
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Quality_Monitoring");

// execute your query
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

// parse the options
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $options = "<option value=\"".$row['AREA']."\">".$row['AREA']."</option>\n  ";
}


// send options
echo $options;

?>
```

And still no joy... can anyone spot what I'm missing?

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655966/send-select-dropdown-to-another-select-dropdown/11656065#11656065

Comment: Have a look at [this question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556920/creating-and-populating-a-select-dynamically?rq=1). You can make your script return HTML markup of the select box from your AJAX call, and then use jQuery to select the element and put it as html: `$("#myelement").html(results)`

Comment: jQuery has `get()`, `post()` & `ajax()` methods. Just read a sample(available plenty if you search in google or here at SO) and try testing it by using in a demo page in your pc. It is better to avoid implementing it directly to your current project. Instead, test it out first and understand it. After having an idea, you could attach it to your ongoing project.

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran `Instead, test it out first and understand it.` can't stress this point enough.

Comment: @sabre: I have seen most of the newbies trying to implement it directly to their ongoing project, and ends up in disaster. Instead, go through the documentation, test it's working in a demo page and monitor the outcomes. Once got everything perfect, implement it in their project. That's what I was saying :)

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran - can you check the code I've added to the main question and see what I'm clearly missing somewhere?  Thankyou!

Comment: @Matt if you could check it out as well... sorry for noobness I don't really get how this forums works in terms of reposting my question

Comment: @ChrisSpalton: Don't you need the data from the PHP page(echoed on GET request)? Read the doc and check the examples: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: @AkileshBChandran - yeah I do need the data from the PHP page.  Read through the doc and checked the examples but unfortunately still don't really have an idea.  Not a trained programmer or developer in anyway, just trying to work this out for a project for work they they've lumbererd me with :)

Answer (score 0):

try this, there are 3 different sections I have included in the code:

```
1) the PHP code
2) The jQuery
3) The select box container
```

---

```
:: Your PHP file (call it getArea.php)
$selectbox = '<select name="region" onchange="jQuery.selectRegion(this.value)">';

$region = $_REQUEST['Region'];      /* Make sure you escape this */

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT AREA FROM Sales_Execs WHERE Region ='$region'";

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Quality_Monitoring");

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$options = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $options .= '<option value="' . $row['AREA'] . '">' . $row['AREA'] . '</option>';
}

echo $selectbox;
echo $options;
echo '</select>';
    exit;
```

---

```
:: Your jquery

jQuery.selectRegion = function selectRegion(regionId)
{
$.get('ajax/getArea.php?region='+regionId,function(data){
    $('#select_container').html(data);
});
}
```

---

```
:: The select box container
<div id="select_container">
<select name="region" onchange="jQuery.selectRegion(this.value)">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi there @Phil Cross thanks for your assistance mate, unfortunately still doesn't work, I just don't understand I'm afraid.